# Image magnify Glass on windows form

Tags: winforms, devexpress

i am trying to use glass magnifier on PictureEdit(devexpress) control in windows form 
we have set  PictureEdit.SizeMode =Squeeze . its important. in our application i am already using Squeeze size mode. 
i am getting problem of calculation of mouse location , for draw rect image onto enalged panel. 
here is code of  PartialMag_Paint event of enalaged panel. in which we show zoomed imaged of mouse pointed area

```
 int srcx = (PartailMagImageView.Location.X + PartailMagImageView.Width / 2);
 int srcy = (PartailMagImageView.Location.Y + PartailMagImageView.Height / 2);

 e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.Image
                    , new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, PartailMagImageView.Width, PartailMagImageView.Height)
                    , new System.Drawing.Rectangle(srcx - ZoomOutRate / 2, srcy - ZoomOutRate / 2, ZoomOutRate, ZoomOutRate)
                    , GraphicsUnit.Pixel);



                Pen mypen = new Pen(Color.Black, 7);
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(mypen, 0, 0, PartailMagImageView.Width - 7, PartailMagImageView.Height - 7);
```

if any one need to see complete code sample. i am attaching sample in dropbox link 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mogmshuiimtvhk7/ImageMagnifyingWindowsForm.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PictureEdit** has the [ViewportToImage](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.PictureEdit.ViewportToImage.method) and [ImageToViewport](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.PictureEdit.ImageToViewport.method) methods allowing you to convert viewport coordinates to the source image coordinates and vice versa.

Comment: yes but problem is that our mouse is on another enalaged panel (in which we are showing zoomed imaged after crop from the original image)  so i am calculating by location of that panel plus image size etc etc.. i maybe wrong. 
u can clear understand after read it. i have attached link of my sample which is with complete dll. exe. u just need to run it. that way u will trace what wrong i am doing .

Comment: you were right. i tried like u said.. and its working fine.. thank you .  
int srcx = (PartailMagImageView.Location.X + PartailMagImageView.Width / 2);                

                int srcy = (PartailMagImageView.Location.Y + PartailMagImageView.Height / 2);
              


                Point point = ViewportToImage(new Point(srcx, srcy));